# How to install recharts in react v18 for typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, recharts

I am trying to install rechart in react v18 and also installed @types/react, @types/recharts still throwing error as

Error: [BABEL]: ENOENT: no such file or directory,'node_modules\recharts\src\index.ts'

```
package.json
{
  "name": "clarity",
  "version": "0.23.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "animate.css": "^4.1.1",
    "history": "^5.3.0",
    "husky": "^8.0.3",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "lint-staged": "^13.2.2",
    "lodash-es": "^4.17.21",
    "markdown-it": "^13.0.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "polished": "^4.2.2",
    "prop-types-exact": "^1.2.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-addons-shallow-compare": "^15.6.3",
    "react-animations": "^1.0.0",
    "react-calendar-heatmap": "^1.9.0",
    "react-day-picker": "^8.8.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-ga": "^3.3.1",
    "react-json-view": "^1.21.3",
    "react-qr-svg": "^2.4.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.1",
    "react-router": "^6.14.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.14.0",
    "react-router-redux": "^4.0.8",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "recharts": "^2.7.2",
    "redux": "^4.2.1",
    "redux-form": "^8.3.10",
    "redux-saga": "^1.2.3",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.4.2",
    "semantic-ui-css": "^2.5.0",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^2.1.4",
    "semver": "^7.5.3",
    "styled-components": "^6.0.0",
    "validator": "^13.9.0",
    "yup": "^1.2.0"
  }, 
  "prettier": {
    "trailingComma": "es5",
    "semi": false,
    "singleQuote": true
  },
 
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rescripts/cli": "^0.0.16",
    "@rescripts/rescript-env": "^0.0.14",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.14",
    "@types/recharts": "^1.8.24",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.1406.0",
    "babel-plugin-recharts": "^2.0.0",
    "chalk": "^5.2.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "enzyme": "^3.11.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.15.7",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^8.0.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.32.2",
    "prettier": "^2.8.8",
    "remote-redux-devtools": "^0.5.16",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^4.9.0"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ]
}
```

### installed packages

yarn add --save recharts

yarn add --dev @types/react

yarn add --dev @types/recharts

I used yarn to add packages, I am expecting to install recharts on react v18 with typescript

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.